# On Pointer Down and On Pointer Up won't work with magnet ~Cardboard ~Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

So currently I'm working with Google Cardboard SDK for Unity. I've been able to do `On Pointer Click` Using Cardboard magnet and it works fine. But I couldn't figure out how to do `On Pointer Up` and `On Pointer Down` as when I pull down the magnet in the cardboard, it doesn't trigger `On Pointer Down` and also when I release the magnet it doesn't trigger `On Pointer Up`.

My question is how to trigger `On Pointer Down` and `On Pointer Up` using magnet on Google Cardboard SDK for Unity?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.
**On pointer up** is an event to the specific object (with this script) in the game.

Cardboard button is just *touch* as fire button, no matter cardboard v1 or v2.

If you want to get **onpointer** like, you can try use **ray** to get hit or not hit.